# How to separate the number with spaces in between using while loop and power function

Tags: c

How do I separate number with 5 spaces in between the numbers without reversing the number using while loop and  pow function?

User can enter any number of numbers. It is not restricted to example just 3.

User will be asked to input n-number of numbers.
User will be asked to enter the numbers.
Print out the numbers without using arrays but only basic while loop and pow function.

Hope to get some help, thank you!

I've tried but below is my result

> Please enter number of digit: 3
>   Please enter the 3 digit number: 123

Output:

> 3   2   1

Expected output:

> 1   2   3

```
int num;
int digit;
// int final;
int n;
int counter;

printf("Number of digits: ");
scanf("%d", &num);

printf("\nDigit number: ", num);
scanf("%d", &n);
counter = 0;

while (counter < n) {
    digit = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    counter++;
    printf("%d   ", digit);
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from using irrelevant tags on your question.  This has nothing to do with C#, Math.h, or pow.

Comment: Secondly, please provide a more complete code sample.  Where is `n` declared?  How does `n` relate to the code you have provided?  What is `num`?

Comment: @Amy I have changed the code, please take a look thank you.

Comment: You [don't need number of digits](https://ideone.com/bXeu9p).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `%n` specifier to confirm that the required number of digits are entered. With an `int` this may be about 10 digits.
Since the first effort produced a reversed result, reverse the number twice to get the desired output.
Pay attention to inputs such as `1000` and `0001` to print the correct leading and trailing zeros.
Check the return of `scanf`, an input of `abc` can't be parsed as an integer and `scanf` will return zero. `scanf` returns the number of items scanned.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void) {
    int num = 0;
    int digits = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int zeros = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int reverse = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int stop = 0;

    printf("Number of digits: ");
    fflush ( stdout);
    if ( 1 == scanf("%d", &digits)) {

        printf("\nDigit number: ");
        fflush ( stdout);
        if ( 1 == scanf(" %n%d%n", &start, &num, &stop)) {
            if ( digits != stop - start) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "enter %d digit number\n", digits);
                return 0;
            }
            counter = 0;
            temp = num;
            zeros = digits;
            while (temp) {//reverse number
                reverse *= 10;
                reverse += temp % 10;
                temp = temp / 10;
                zeros--;//deduct for leading zeros
            }
            counter = 0;
            while ( zeros) {//print leading zeros
                counter++;
                zeros--;
                printf ( "0  ");
            }
            while (counter < digits) {//reverse again and print
                digit = reverse % 10;
                reverse = reverse / 10;
                counter++;
                printf("%d   ", digit);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "could not parse number\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf ( stderr, "could not parse number of digits\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Print out the numbers without using arrays but only basic while loop and pow function.

This specifies use of `pow()`, a floating point function, to solve an integer problem - not a good strategy to learn.

Further, `"%d"` is an *array* so "without using arrays" is unclear.

---

The following meets the restrictions imposed.

```
void foo(int count, int i) {
  if (count > 1) {
    foo(count - 1, i / 10);
    for (int space = 0; space < 5; space++) {
      putchar(' ');
    }
  }
  putchar(i%10 + '0');
}

int main() {
  foo(3, 123);
}
```

Output:

```
1     2     3
```